# Why rewarded video ad type is not showing in create placement at Facebook Audience Network?

Tags: android, admob, facebook-audience-network, rewardedvideoad

I have a gaming app and  I am using admob for mediation. For banner and interstitial ad I am using admob and Facebook Audience Network. But for rewarded ad I want to use Facebook Rewarded Video ad too. But when I am trying to create a placement there is no reward type ad. It is showing below ad types
1) Native 2) Banner 3) Interstitial 4) Medium Rectangle

No reward ad unit. What is the problem?
Admob doc showing FAN supports rewarded video 
https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/mediation/facebook

Comment: Strange enough, I too cannot see the reward video type ad. How did you solve it?

Comment: I am having the same problem did anyone find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

You can apply for rewarded video ads through email as mentioned in this [post](https://www.facebook.com/help/publisher/862434743958571?helpref=faq_content)

Answer (score 2):

Note: In-stream and rewarded video ad placements are only available for select publishers on an invitation-only basis.
https://www.facebook.com/help/audiencenetwork/909759812477057

Comment: Thanks @robert. How can I get the invitation? Any idea?

Comment: @MobileDev did you find how to request reward ads cuz I am facing the same problem. Thank you.